# Given $Y\sim U(0, 1)$, what is the expected value of $X \sim U(0, Y)$?

Tags: probability, integration

> Given $Y\sim U(0, 1)$, what is the expected value of $X \sim U(0, Y)$?

Generally, the solution for this problem can be generalised as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x) dx$ but what is $f(x)$ here?

Comment: $EX=E(E(X|Y))$ This is called the tower property of conditional expectation.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy. Your comment is most enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X \sim U(0, Y)$, we have $$E(X|Y = y) = \frac{y}{2}.$$
By the Tower Rule, $E(X)$ is then $E(E(X|Y = y))$:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y}{2} \operatorname{pdf}Y(y) dy$$
Evaluating the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y}{2} 1 dy= \frac{y^2}{4} \bigg|_0^1 = \frac{1}{4}.$$